# Compiler error when referring to type in a separate class

Tags: c++, oop, visual-c++, crtp

I am defining 3 classes in C++ and trying to make maximum use of Curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP). I am using VS 2017.

Code:

```
`

template<typename Outer>
class OuterClass <Outer, uint32_t> {
    using datatype = uint32_t;

static uintptr_t GetAddr(void const volatile* const ptr) {
            auto const addr1 =            get_addr();
            auto const addr_virtual =     ptr;
            auto const baseAddr =         Outer::base_addr;
            uintptr_t const addressCalcd = uintptr_t(baseAddr) + uintptr_t( addr_virtual - addr1 );
        return addressCalcd;
    };
};

template<typename Outer>
class OuterClass <Outer, uint64_t> {
    using datatype = uint64_t;

static uintptr_t GetAddr(void const volatile* const ptr) {
            auto const addr1 =            get_addr();
            auto const addr_virtual =     ptr;
            auto const baseAddr =         Outer::base_addr;
            uintptr_t const addressCalcd = uintptr_t(baseAddr) + uintptr_t( addr_virtual - addr1 );
        return addressCalcd;
    };
};

template<typename Inner, typename Outer>
struct InnerClass {

    GetAddVal CastVl()  const volatile { 
    uint32_t addrl = uint32_t(Outer::GetAddr(static_cast<const volatile R*>(this)));
        return VAL_CAST{ addrl };
    }
    operator Outer::datatype() const volatile {
        return RegBlock<Outer, Outer::datatype>::readReg(*this);
    }
    operator Outer::datatype() const {
        return RegBlock<Outer, Outer::datatype>::readReg(*this);
    }
    void operator=(Inner const  & x) volatile;
    void operator=(const Outer::datatype x) volatile;
};
```

The errors are in the InnerClass. Firstly,

`uint32_t addrl = uint32_t(Outer::GetAddr(static_cast<const volatile R*>(this)));`

is perfectly fine. I can refer to the static class Outer::GetAddr no problem.

However, I cannot refer the typedef'd

`operator Outer::datatype() const volatile {`

Error: C2833 "operator qualified-name" is not recognized operator or type

This is also an error for :

`void operator=(const Outer::datatype x) volatile;`

C2805  binary "operator =" has too few parameters.

Why can I refer to static classes using the :: and not anything typedef'd ? Should I consider nesting the "InnerClass" inside the "OuterClass" ? Ideally I don't want to have nested classes at all.

Comment: `template<typename Outer> class OuterClass <Outer, uint32_t>` Not sure what this is? Did you mean to specialise? GCC gives loads of errors from the very top of your code.

Comment: `datatype` is dependent on the template parameters. That's means you need to specify that it's a type and not a member by using `typename Outer::datatype`.